# Geolocation script issues

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I've some issues with a geolocation script I'm working on and maybe someone could help me here :).

For this script I have 4 files :

**functions.js**:

```
function geolocation(){
  GMaps.geolocate({
    success: function(position) {
        var userLat = position.coords.latitude;
        var userLng = position.coords.longitude;

        var dataString = 'userLat='+userLat+'&userLng='+userLng;

        $.ajax({
            type     : 'POST',
            url      : 'getEvents.php',
            data     : dataString,
            dataType : 'text',
            success  : function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert('Echec de la localisation...');
    },
    not_supported: function() {
        alert('Votre navigateur ne supporte pas la géolocalisation...');
    }
});
```

}

**index.php:**

```
<?php require 'php/getEvents.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <?php include('inc/head.html'); ?>

    <body>
        <div class="mosaic">
            <?php echo visitorMosaicBox($data); ?>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                geolocation();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**getEvents.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require 'db-connect.php';
    require 'lib.php';

    $userLat = $_POST['userLat'];
    $userLng = $_POST['userLng'];
    $area    = 10;
    $i       = 0;
    $data    = array();

    if($userLat != '' && $userLng != ''){
        if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
            echo 'Logged';
        }else{
            try{
                $sql = "SELECT restaurants.cover, restaurants.name, restaurants.address, restaurants.location, restaurants.zip, events.title, events.trailer, events.id
                        FROM events 
                        LEFT JOIN restaurants ON restaurants.id = events.fk_restaurants";
                $req = $db->query($sql);    
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                echo 'Erreur: '.$e->getMessage();
            }

            while($res = $req->fetch()){
                $fetchAddress = $res['address'].', '.$res['zip'].' '.$res['location'];
                $fixedAddress = str_replace(' ','+',$fetchAddress);

                $geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$fixedAddress.'&sensor=false');
                $output  = json_decode($geocode);

                $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
                $lng = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

                $distance = distance($userLat, $userLng, $lat, $lng, false);

                if($distance <= $area){
                    $data[$i] = array( 
                        "id" => $res['id'],
                        "name" => $res['name'], 
                        "cover" => $res['cover'],
                        "address" => $fetchAddress,
                        "title" => $res['title'] ,
                        "trailer" => $res['trailer'],    
                    );
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }   
    }else{
        $data = 'ERROR';
    }
?>
```

**lib.php :**

```
<?php
    function visitorMosaicBox($array){
        for($i=0; $i<sizeOf($array);$i++){
            $html  = '<div class="box" id="box-'.$i.'">';
            $html .= '<img src="'.$array[$i]['cover'].'" alt="'.$array[$i]['name'].'" />';
            $html .= '<span class="ribbon"></span>';
            $html .= '<div class="back"></div>';
            $html .= '<div class="infos" id="event-'.$array[$i]['id'].'">';
            $html .= '<p class="msg"></p>';

            $html .= '<div class="txt-1">';
            $html .= '<span class="sits"><span class="dinners">5</span></span>';
            $html .= '<h3>'.$array[$i]['title'].'<span class="block">'.$array[$i]['name'].'</span></h3>';
            $html .= '<ul class="actions">';
            $html .= '<li><a href="#" class="event-share">Partager</a></li>';
            $html .= '<li><a href="signup.php" class="join joinIn">Participer</a></li>';
            $html .= '<li class="last"><a href="#" class="event-info">Info</a></li>';
            $html .= '</ul>';
            $html .= '</div>'; // Fin de .txt-1

            $html .= '<div class="txt-2">';
            $html .= '<h3>'.$array[$i]['title'].'</h3>';
            $html .= '<p>'.$array[$i]['trailer'].'</p>';
            $html .= '<a href="#" class="close">Fermer</a>';
            $html .= '</div>'; // Fin de .txt-2

            $html .= '</div>'; // Fin de .infos
            $html .= '</div>'; // Fin de .box

            return $html;
        }
    }
?>
```

So now what's that's supposed to do...

**1**/  **functions.js** geolocates the visitor, gets his coordonates (lat,lng) and send them to my **getEvents.php**

**2**/  **getEvents.php** receives the coordonates from **functions.js**, and compare them with the results from the database.

**3**/  If the distance between the result and the user is lower than the area (10) then I store all the datas from the result in my array **$data**.

**4**/  The function **visitorMosaicBox()** creates as many divs as there are results in my array.

**5**/  In **index.php**, I simply call **visitorMosaicBox()** by passing my array **$data**.

My problem is that **no divs are created even if there are results**. I receive the visitor's coordonates in my **getEvents.php** file but in my **index.php** file the coordonates doesn't exists.

Does anyone know why my coordonates can't pass from my **getEvents.php** file to my **index.php** file please ? Any solution ?

If I split my script in these 4 files it's because I'll need to do other stuffs on my **getEvents.php** file depending on the visitor is connected or not, etc...

Thanks and sorry for this long question.
Antho